# How to use Computed property names in React to set state

Tags: reactjs

How can i use **Computed property names** to geta state in react?

I mean, one code say more then 1000 words:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    name: 'joao',
    age: 18
  }
  set = (s, v) => {
      this.setState({
          [s]: v
      })
  }
  get = (s) => {
    // ---------- <HERE> ----------
    //return this.state.[s];
    // ---------- </HERE> ----------
    // ---------- <INSTEAD OF> ----------
    if(s == 'name') return this.state.name;
    else if(s == 'age') return this.state.age;
    // ---------- </INSTEAD OF> ----------
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.set('name', 'maria')}>Change Name</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.set('age', 20)}>Change Age</button>
        <br/>{this.get('name')}
        <br/>{this.get('age')}
        <br/><Link to="/news">Go to NEWS</Link>
      </div>
    );
    };
}
```

The set is working, but the get, i cant get the value of state just using []
This code is just a example

Comment: `return this.state[s];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since this.state is an object, you have multiple syntax for accessing the property of an object like:

objectName.property         // person.age

objectName["property"]      // person["age"]

objectName[expression]      // x = "age"; person[x]

your solution would be:

```
get = (s) => {
    return this.state[s];
  }

or just on JSX

<br/>{this.state.name}
<br/>{this.state.age}
```

Answer (score 0):

React does not have computed properties like other JavaScript frameworks e.g. Angular or Vue, in other words there are no computed properties in React, however we can achieve this behavior or effect by using functions, one way is to use [handleChange()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-handlechange-function-in-react-component/) function. Since handleChange() function runs on every keystroke to update the React state, the displayed value will update as the user types. Take a look at [Controlled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) by [React](https://reactjs.org/).

```
handleChange(e){
       this.setState({[e.target.id]: e.target.value })
}
```